# ¿Hay algún término para diferenciar "fecha" de "fecha y hora"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, informática, tiempo

En el mundo de la informática, y en particular en las bases de datos, es muy común diferencias las fechas de las fechas que tienen también hora, minuto y segundo (y milisegundo, si me apuras).

En término informático esta distinción suele marcarse con un *date* (fecha) y *datetime* (fecha y hora), que seguramente no son usadas en el habla coloquial pero que se explican por sí solas.

En castellano usamos [*fecha*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HhpCnjk) de una forma un tanto genérica, pues ya el DLE muestra que:

> *Del desus. fecha [carta] 'hecha [la carta]', fórmula que precedía a la indicación del lugar y tiempo en los que se redactó.*
>
> 1. Indicación del tiempo, y a veces del lugar, en que se hace o sucede algo, especialmente al principio o al final de un escrito. *La fecha de una carta, de un cuadro.*

que sigue con otras acepciones:

> 2. f. Tiempo en que se hace o sucede algo. *Enero de 2001 fue la fecha decidida.*
>
> 3. f. Día completo o día determinado. *Estamos a tres fechas del inicio de la primavera. Navidad y Año Nuevo son fechas muy señaladas.*
>
> 4. f. Tiempo o momento actuales. *No hay una explicación satisfactoria hasta LA fecha.*
>
> 5. f. U. en aposición tras un sustantivo que designa el plazo para el cumplimiento o vencimiento de algo, especialmente una letra o un pago. *El crédito vence a un mes fecha.*

En la primera de las entradas vimos que la "caja" fecha contiene de todo: lugar, día, mes, año... e incluso no sería descabellado también encontrar hora.

Volviendo a la aplicación informática, doy por hecho que al decir *fecha y hora* estaríamos hablando del *datetime*. Pero ¿existe alguna forma de utilizar *fecha* para indicar que solamente nos referimos al día, mes y año, sin que se espere una hora?

Comment: Pienso como @walen y de hecho creo que el propio título de la pregunta tiene la respuesta y se diferencia diciendo únicamente "fecha" o "fecha y hora"

Comment: @walen sí, a qué palabra usar en castellano, y en el ámbito de la informática, para referirnos a _fecha_ como tipo _date_ a secas, implicando la ausencia de hora.

Comment: Creo que deberías recurrir al sintagma nominal "fecha y hora", sería lo más correcto en castellano...

Comment: Si quieres diferenciar, podrías decir algo como «fecha», «hora» y, propondría, «momento» (para fecha y hora).

Comment: @guifa uy, [_momento_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pbn1zcv) creo que podría añadir más incertidumbre. Así a bote pronto, me hace pensar en el concepto de la Física (_cantidad de movimiento_).

Comment: @fedorqui yo pensaba más en frases como «el momento en que pasó tal y tal», pero es cierto que en español estas dos palabras son iguales (en inglés son diferentes, *moment* --> momento de tiempo, *momentum* --> momento de física).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En español, *fecha* es exclusivamente para describir año, mes y día. Nunca contempla el uso en conjunto con la hora. Por ello, si descartamos el mundo de la informática, jamás existe la confusión entre *fecha* con *fecha y hora*, sencillamente porque no existe un concepto unificador para el segundo término.
Respecto de la informática, debido a que en ésta existen registros que permiten incorporar simultáneamente la información de fecha y hora, es que en inglés (idioma más flexible que el español) surgen dos palabras, *datetime* y *timestamp*, que describen justamente la información completa de fecha y hora, además de un mal llamado comando, *date*, que refleja también esa información en conjunto.
En el ámbito informático, el español toma prestadas las palabras del inglés, por ello generalmente yo escucho alguna de esas palabras en inglés cuando se habla de fecha y hora en español.

Comment: «El inglés es más flexible que el español»… Como traductor, estoy harto de esa cantaleta, que es falsa.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que se utiliza la palabra muy rara *cronomarcador* para *fecha y hora* pero probablemente sólo en el ámbito informático, y especialmente en relación con SAP.

Por ejemplo aquí es un extracto de une respuesta encontrada en un [foro de usuarios de SAP](http://www.mundosap.com/foro/showthread.php?t=3581):

> Tienes el elemento de datos TZNTSTMPS "Cronomarcador UTC en forma breve (AAAAMMDDhhmmss)".
>
> También tienes el TZNTIMESTP "Cronomarcador (fecha + hora)"

A continuación un uso sin relación con SAP, pero se trata mas de un dispositivo que fije la fecha y hora en lugar de la fecha y hora misma:

> *[5.3.4.2.6.7 - Cronomarcador](http://www.academia.edu/15775506/Cap%C3%ADtulo_5_Inspecciones_de_Establecimientos_SUBCAP%C3%8DTULO_5.3_DESARROLLO_DE_EVIDENCIAS)*
>
> El reloj interno dentro de la cámara que registra la información de hora y fecha en el archivo de la imagen. Fije el cronomarcador para el lugar donde se toman las fotografías o videos. En este uso, el cronomarcador no se refiere a imprimir la hora y fecha dentro de la imagen fotográfica, aunque también pueden serlo, tal y como pueden hacerlo algunas cámaras a película

<sub>Postdata: ¡Por favor no duden en corregir mi español!</sub>

Comment: @walen Sí, es verdad que casi todas las referencias que se encuentran son relativas a SAP. Respuesta revisada

Comment: ¡Popularicemos, pues, el término, que es muy lindo!